# Rubymine(Jetbrains) local server. Can I get it to run from localhost root?

Tags: localhost, webstorm, rubymine, jetbrains-ide

Currently when I open the html file I'm working on it takes me to

```
http://localhost:63342/project-folder/index.html
```

Is there a way to set Rubymine to run my project from the root, eg.

```
http://localhost:63342/index.html
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`http://localhost:63342/index.html` -- *you **cannot** have this kind of URL **with built-in web server*** .. as IDE does not know what project to serve (as it works for ALL your projects a not only currently opened).

When built-in web server is in use, the URL **has to have** some **hint** (`PROJECT_NAME`) that would tell what project to serve (where to take files from).

Built-in web server supports 2 kind of URLs (both of them will serve the same file):

```
http://localhost:63342/PROJECT_NAME/index.html
http://PROJECT_NAME:63342/index.html
```

If you want 2nd URL, then you will have to do these steps:

1. Create Deployment entry (`Settings | Deployment`) and **mark it as Default** for this project. The URL defined there (`http://PROJECT_NAME:63342/`) will be used when opening pages from within IDE.
2. In your `hosts` file (or your local DNS server, if you have one) define an entry that would point `PROJECT_NAME` to your IP. For example (for `hosts` file): `127.0.0.1 PROJECT_NAME`

Comment: For beginners like me. Your hosts file is often in the following location (on Windows):
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Comment: Followed the instructions but the URL always shows "404 Not Found". So the hosts file and port are correct, but WebStorm replies with 404.

Comment: @Mikhail This kind of URL: `http://PROJECT_NAME:63342/index.html` ?? AFAIK this functionality has been removed by now...

Comment: actually got it working after an hour. As the answer says - the url has to match the project name. I had issues because my project name was same as actual url of the website.

Comment: @Mikhail Hmm.. odd... as I read few times responses from JB support team member that this has been removed/should not work any more. Maybe I've got confused with something else ... or your IDE version is older/still has it. Not sure. Anyway: good to know.