# PhpStorm - CSS files link to root of server and not project root

Tags: html, css, localhost, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Basically I'm trying to run a HTML file in PhpStorm on localhost.

My issue is the fact that my CSS file have paths relative to the root of the server (as they should) but in PhpStorm another folder is automatically added for the project.

In short, my CSS files link to:

```
localhost:port/css/style.css
```

While PhpStorm makes the location be:

```
localhost:port/projectname/css/style.css
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks! 
-Jamie

Comment: This `localhost:port/projectname` means that PhpStorm's own built-in simple web server is used. If you want to use your own server -- configure Deployment entry (`Settings | Deployment`) and mark it as Default for this project.

Comment: @LazyOne
I'm fine with using the built in server. However obviously I want my CSS files to point relatively to the root of the server and not to the project folder (since the project folder is not gonna be on the real web server)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24908091/783119

Answer (score 0):

If you like to change the default web path on built-in web server, you have to re-configure the server by editing your system hosts file accordingly - see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8988#comment=27-577559.