# CakePHP and PhpStorm - Routing Error?

Tags: cakephp, phpstorm

I am trying to setup a new CakePHP project in PhpStorm. However, when I open the project in Chrome, it directs me to `localhost:63342/Werkbon/`. I'd rather expected it to direct me to `localhost:63342/` (so the root).

Now I have added a new table named `Orders` and created the Controller, View and Model using the `bake` console function. I cannot seem to display the webpage associated with it (tried `localhost:63342/Orders/`, `localhost:63342/Werkbon/Orders/` etc. => display a 404 Not Found error), but it does not seem to work...

I think the solution is pretty simple, but my Google does not seem to help here...

Comment: You are using PhpStorm's built-in simple web server .. which requires PROJECT_NAME part of the URL (in `localhost:63342/PROJECT_NAME/`) to be present in order to identify what project to serve.

Comment: Yes, ok... But how can I get to display the Orders without modifying the routes.php file? Shouldn't the link 'localhost:63342/Werkbon/Orders/' work out-of-the-box?

Comment: 3 possible solutions: 1) use [PHP's built-in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) 2) Use proper web-server (Apache/nginx/IIS/etc.) -- be it vanilla one (original) or part of some bundle (e.g. WAMP/XAMPP/MAMP/etc) 3) Configure PhpStorm's built-in web server to use `http://PROJECT_NAME:63342/` kind of URLs -- see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24908091/783119

Comment: Tried Option 1 and this works perfectly. Thanks for the fast response!