# PhpStorm setting the Document Root

Tags: phpstorm

- PhpStorm 2020.1
- Windows 10
- Apache installed with XAMPP.

I am trying to get PhpStorm's built in server to recognize a document root. PhpStorm keeps running `localhost:[port]/[project folder]/default.html`. It should be running `localhost:[port]/default.html`

Because it keeps placing the project folder into the path, all the links fail.

I have edited the `c:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf` file to change the document root and confirmed it in the console, that didn't work. Even setting the document root to the project folder didn't work.

It appears there is a setting or a different conf file that need to be adjusted, but I can't find it or figure out what is missing from the documentation.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/24908091/783119 for built-in web server URLs, but I'm not super sure if it still works like that. **P.S.** If you have Apache then why not use the actual Apache to serve your web site and not PhpStorm's built-in simple webserver?

Comment: I want to be able to use the debugging functions in phpstorm

Comment: *"I want to be able to use the debugging functions in phpstorm"* What it has to do with web server software or the URL used to serve the page? The answer is -- nothing. Configure Xdebug and you can use IIS or nginx or even [PHP web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) to serve your pages -- no difference.

Comment: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/ 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html or look for some video tutorials on YouTube / specific for your PHP framework or environment (if they exist)

Comment: If you want to right click on the file in PhpStorm use "Debug PHP page" kind of functionality and it opens that URL with the PROJECT_NAME in it, then you need to configure Deployment entry ("In Place" type is fine) and mark it as Default for this project. When you use "Open in Browser" or alike functionality in IDE where it requires IDE to build an URL, it looks for default deployment entry and takes base URL from there. If you have no deployment entry or have but it's not marked as Default, then IDE builds URL for PhpStorm's built-in simple web server (which has project name in URL).